# Diode circuit analysis with two diodes in series

Tags: diodes, circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHGOIk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the above schematic the CVD model is being used, with a voltage drop of 0.6 V, for all three diodes. The input voltage sweeps from -10 V, to +10 V. In this homework assignment my task is to sketch a current vs input voltage diagram for all three diodes. In my analysis, I started from the -10V input and did a circuit approximation for that single voltage and tried to find when one of the parameters defining either the voltage or the current for any diode changes its sign, or more precisely, one of the diodes turns off or on. This is my diagram for that specific scenario:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fccske.png)</sup>

The expression for the current is I=(4.4V - Vin)/R1. This current is always >0 for all input voltages that satisfy the inequality Vin<4.4 Volts. However a simulation I performed in LTspice revealed that the diode D1 actually stops conducting much earlier, at Vin=0.6V. [image]

This inevitably led me to seek another analytical way to obtain the same result as above. This is the equation according 3,to KVL:Ud3+Ud2-0.6-Vin=0. Both Ud3 and Ud2 are <0.6V. Rearrangin the previous equation I got Ud2=Vin+0.6-Ud3<0.6, and thus Vin

Comment: and thus Vin<0.6V. Is my approach here correct? What about the diodes in series? If one is non conducting, the other one is nonconducting as well?

Comment: You can consider 2 diodes in series as a single diode but with double the forward voltage so 1.2 V instead of 0.6 V for a single diode.

Comment: I might be going off topic here, but can we do the same when we have a Zener diode and a  normal one connected in series too? I have another example in which a zener diode is connected via its cathode to a normal diode's cathode(in series). So accordingly, we put there a single diode but with a voltage drop of Vzd-Vf?

Comment: Why could we not ? The diodes don't "see" each other. The voltage across a diode depend on the current and it's direction. That is all. But watch out with zeners, the forward voltage is usually normal. like 0.6 V but in reverse mode they start to conduct when the voltage becomes higher than the zener voltage.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. If you have time, put it as an answer.

Comment: I just wanted a way to thank you, but since this is a new profile here, I don't have enough rep to upvote your comment.

Comment: Doesn't matter :-) You learned something, that's enough for me :-)

Comment: On the topic of mixing and matching diodes in series, make sure to remember that while the *DC* behaviour can be modeled as a single diode, the behaviour during transients is more complex.